# Where is the file name list stored?

Tags: python, string, list, ftplib

This simple code:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov")
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd("allData/5/MOD11A1/2012/193/")
a = ftp.retrlines('NLST')
```

Logs into an ftp, changes the current directory, and lists the names of the files contained within the current directory.

If I afterwards check what variable `a` contains inside, I get this:

```
>>> print (a)
226 Listing completed.
```

So, I don't understand where the list of the file names is stored.
Any idea?
I want to apply some regular expression operations to the file names later on.

Comment: Just check the path `os.path.abspath('.')`

Comment: @Abhijit That will just print the location of the script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retrlines` [prints to stdout by default](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines). You can collect the output in a list, however, by using the second (callback) argument like this:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov")
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd("allData/5/MOD11A1/2012/193/")
filenames = []
ftp.retrlines('NLST', filenames.append)
print(filenames)
```